# Core Data NSFetchedResultsController: Error when debugging on device (Unable to generate SQL for predicate)

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsdate, nspredicate

i have a weird exeption when i debug my app on my device. debugging in simulator works as expected.

- i use core data for storing my data
- relationships in model are as follows: Location <-> LocationDetails ->> HappyHour
- i use NSFetchedResultsController to populate a UITableView
- i'm also pretty new to objective-c develpoment

i need to have a SUBQUERY to get to the attributes of the HappyHour entity.

Like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(0 != SUBQUERY(details.%K, $hh, ($hh.startTime < %@) AND ($hh.endTime > %@)).@count)", weekdayString, theDate, theDate];
```

ONLY on the DEVICE i get this error/exeption:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to generate SQL for predicate (0 != SUBQUERY(details.hh_montag, $hh, $hh.startTime < CAST(316482000.000000, "NSDate") AND $hh.endTime > CAST(316482000.000000, "NSDate")).@count) (problem on RHS)'

0   CoreFoundation                      0x32cf964f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3313cc5d objc_exception_throw + 24
    2   CoreData                            0x3228a829 -[NSSQLGenerator newSQLStatementForFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:] + 688
    3   CoreData                            0x3228a2eb -[NSSQLAdapter _newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:] + 378
    4   CoreData                            0x3228a169 -[NSSQLAdapter newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:] + 16
    5   CoreData                            0x3228a005 -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] + 288
    6   CoreData                            0x322892c5 -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] + 420
    7   CoreData                            0x32288875 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 304
    8   CoreData                            0x32287dd5 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 896
    9   CoreData                            0x3228669f -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 374
    10  CoreData                            0x322b9d7f -[NSFetchedResultsController performFetch:] + 766
    11  HappyHourRadar                      0x0003e723 -[ResultViewController viewDidLoad] + 86
...
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Signal received: SIGABRT (Aborted)

Process finished with exit code -1

---

At **[ResultViewController viewDidLoad] +86**

i call

**[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]**

---

in the console i also get this message:

unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).

---

As i haven't found anything that could help me, i guess it's either something really weird, or i just messed up something pretty standard, that i can't find because of my limited objective c background...

Anyway, i would be very glad if someone could give a hint, so i can continue without having to rewrite my entire application model layer to something dirty (like fetching all entries and holding them in an array and process filter functions...stuff like that ;) )

---

edit:

here is the model graph. from this auto-generated the model files.

[Link to Image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/232/datamodel.png/)

generated HappyHour class:

```
@interface HappyHour :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * endTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * startTime;

@end
```

Comment: Can you share the definition of that entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured it out. Hopefully this will help someone, who is as blind, tired or whatever as myself. ;)

These bold marked passages clearly don't match:

- Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to generate SQL for predicate (0 != SUBQUERY(details.**hh_montag**, $hh, $hh.startTime < CAST(316482000.000000, "NSDate") AND $hh.endTime > CAST(316482000.000000, "NSDate")).@count) (problem on RHS)'

and

> @class Location;
>
> @interface LocationDetails :
> NSManagedObject   { }
>
> @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * phone;
>
> ...
>
> @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet * **hh_monday**;
>
> ...
>
> @end

**The final solution was:**

```
NSTimeInterval secondsPerDay = 7 * 60 * 60;
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];

SOLUTION >> [f setLocale: [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_UK"] autorelease]];

NSString *weekdayString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hh_%@", [[f stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-secondsPerDay]] lowercaseString]];
```

---

**Golden Rule:**

Always keep in mind, that a device will work differently in a different location/language.

So, maybe avoid producing key selectors(?) from location/language-dependent classes like NSDate(Formatter).
Or make sure, that these classes return the same values for every case. (Hopefully something I have taken care of with this solution...correct me if I got that wrong.)